# How do I set a default selection to a Listbox in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a multi-select ListBox in MS Access 2010.  On form load, I want the value "Incremental Funding" to automatically be selected.  How is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
With MyListBoxName
    .SetFocus
    For x = Abs(.ColumnHeads) To (.ListCount - 1)
        If (.ItemData(x) = "Incremental Funding") Then
            .Selected(x) = True
            MsgBox (.Selected(x))
        End If
    Next
End With
```

Comment: What does the .SetFocus do here?

Comment: Just sets the focus to the listbox control.  Some controls need the focus to accomplish certain tasks, like scrolling through its contents.